# Internal Trace Transactions Python

Tags: etherscan, web3.py, python, internal-transactions

I've been trying to figure out the best way to get the Net internal/trace transactions using python for a specific transaction hash.

I have read other topics on the forum that say that these are not recorded on the blockchain, so web3.py is not an option and you have to use a specialized kind of EVM to simulate a given transaction using the contract, I'm trying to avoid that, since it seems complicated on python...

I'm considering now using etherscan site [Net Internal Transactions](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0f6994bd16df20f0d0992a607ab78e8be1a05cb07b411437fed2fec83be1bc9c), I might resort to webscraping with beautifulsoup, but I don't know if anyone knows of a better alternative with python based api that does this (takes in a hash, returns internal transactions) that interacts with either etherscan/infura...

Comment: You should definitely consider using Etherscan Developers API instead of scraping their website. In particularly [this one](https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts) (scroll down a bit in order to get to the 'Internal Transactions' part).

Comment: thanks looks like a great option... I'll definitely have a look... Yes definitely a good option for this. Probably I'll use that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm considering now using etherscan site Net Internal Transactions, I might resort to webscraping with beautifulsoup, but I don't know if anyone knows of a better alternative with python based api that does this (takes in a hash, returns internal transactions) that interacts with either etherscan/infura...

You should definitely consider using *Etherscan Developers APIs* instead of scraping their website.

In particularly [this one](https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts) (scroll down a bit in order to get to the *Internal Transactions* part).